# Aerobic Video Game type exercises

Tags: cardio, hiit, interval-training, video-games

I am looking for video game type programs for aerobic exercise I should have a look at.
What I am looking for is:

(1) To be able to set time, intensity and perhaps physical difficulty.

(2) To record what I am doing, preferably with the possibility to combine it with heart rate data.

(3) Some kind of feedback, measure of what I am doing.  A bit fun.

The idea is to repeat workouts the same way, but have the possibility to select for slightly higher intensity/difficulty.

Can be various combinations involving coordination (like dance), mobility, strength, and compound full body (Like burpees or kettlebell).

In my case I prefer low impact and not rapid movements (No running, Dance should be like low impact zumba, and boxing or regular burpees are not ideal).
5-15 min sessions  Should be indoor.

The core exercises would be step/squat type movements - low impact, low disturbance, muscular and functional.

Cardio equipment in gyms typically works this zay.  You can select different varied programs, time and a level.  Next time you can do the same or increase a bit.

Have an X-Box and a Wii with a balance board.

Comment: What are you asking for? Video games that look at you while doing kettlebell workouts?

Comment: For example.  There are different ways to sense and give feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most fitting thing would be Zwift. You’d need a bike and a smart trainer to set it up, which could be cost prohibitive, but it offers all the things you are asking for.

You can join races, do FTP training, and get instant feedback on your workout.

I think Zwift is now available with certain treadmills as well, but I haven’t looked into it.

Answer (score -1):

Try [Zombies, Run!](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/zombies-run/id503519713?mt=8). Great app that involves you running from 'zombies' chasing you.

Comment: This looks a bit like a promotion.  Can you please say more?

Comment: I literally linked you to the app page with all the information you could use (a paragraph or two along with pictures) to make a conclusion as to whether you'd enjoy the game or not. What else do you want?

Comment: I want the question to be broad, but this is quite different from a video game in the living room.  As the chance that your post  is promotion spam is greater you should explain how it relates to the points in the question.  (It should also be quite clear that this is not what I am looking for personally)

Comment: @mobcityzkore - What we expect, is a complete answer here. Explain why it would fit what the original poster is looking for. Just a "Try this" with a link is not an acceptable answer for SE standards.

Comment: Here is the relevant help section: fitness.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer and I would also invite you to reread the Be Nice policy.